# Rename columns with multiple value dictionary

Tags: arrays, pandas, rename

I have a dataframe and would like to rename the columns based on a dictionary with multiple values per key. The dictionary key has the desired column name, and the values hold possible old column names. The column names have no  pattern.

```
import pandas as pd
column_dict = {'a':['col_a','col_1'], 'b':['col_b','col_2'], 'c':'col_c','col_3']}

df = pd.DataFrame([(1,2.,'Hello'), (2,3.,"World")], columns=['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'])
```

Function to replace text with key

```
def replace_names(text, dict):
    for key in dict:
    text = text.replace(dict[key],key)
return text


replace_names(df.columns.values,column_dict)
```

Gives an error when called on column names

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.rename(columns=...)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) if you supply a dict which maps old column names to new column names:

```
import pandas as pd
column_dict = {'a':['col_a','col_1'], 'b':['col_b','col_2'], 'c':['col_c','col_3']}
df = pd.DataFrame([(1,2.,'Hello'), (2,3.,"World")], columns=['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'])

col_map = {col:key for key, cols in column_dict.items() for col in cols}
df = df.rename(columns=col_map)
```

yields

```
   a    b      c
0  1  2.0  Hello
1  2  3.0  World
```

Comment: Perfect, much simpler!